# SQL Server query update

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I have 2 tables. I need to update data the data in `tableB`, populate it with data from `tableA`.

But the problem is the design (note: I can't change the design because its a ready made system. I'll just have to deal with the fail).

Lets say `tableA` (2 columns) the data source is structured like so:

```
ID | NAME
1    dude
2    dud
3    bro
4    broo
5    killa
6    whale
--ID is an index and NAME is UNIQUE
```

Now `tableB` (6 columns) the destination (hard part for me):

```
ID1 | NAME1 | ID2 | NAME2 | ID3 | NAME3
1     dude    2     dud     3     bro
4     broo    5     killa   6     whale
--All columns here has UNIQUE data though it is not set on the design.
--and so on until the end.
```

Now what I want to do is `UPDATE` the names in `tableA` to the names in `tableB` corresponding to there ID's.

Example:

```
ID from TableA is 1
Find ID=1 on TableB
If ID=1 then UPDATE the next column to 'dude'
```

Example end of TableA is:

```
ID | Name
9997 sweet
9998 jess
9999 grape
--The END
```

Example end of TableB is:

```
ID1 | NAME1 | ID2 | NAME2 | ID3 | NAME3
9997  sweet1  9998  jess1   9999  grape1
--The END
```

Please help me.

Note:

- All given table names and column names are for example purposes only.
- There are more columns in the tables, but they don't need to be changed/altered so I did not include an example of them.
- The reason for this is that the data in `TableB` has been changed and is not matching the correct data anymore.
- So I need to repopulate `TableB` with the correct data, and the only source for the correct data is `TableA`.
- Lastly, I am using SQL Server 2008.

----- edit ------

Here is my final query that worked perfectly:

```
UPDATE CHAR_INFOR
SET
    CHARID0=(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,substring(char_data, 9, 16)) from CHAR_DATA0 A WHERE A.CHAR_KEY=CHAR0_KEY), 
CHARID1=(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,substring(char_data, 9, 16)) from CHAR_DATA0 A WHERE A.CHAR_KEY=CHAR1_KEY), 
CHARID2=(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,substring(char_data, 9, 16)) from CHAR_DATA0 A WHERE A.CHAR_KEY=CHAR2_KEY);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like standard SQL should work:

```
UPDATE TableB B 
SET Name1=(SELECT Name from TableA A where A.ID=ID1), 
Name2=(SELECT Name from TableA A where A.ID=ID2), 
Name3=(SELECT Name from TableA A where A.ID=ID3);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of MSSQL you are using but if the version you use support the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) keyword I highly recommend using it. Basically you can "pivot" a table and turn your rows into columns using it.

If you do not have this then the alternative is to use a temp table and do the pivot yourself. It's kind of a long procedure but fairly straight forward. Here is an article on using a temp table for [dynamic pivoting in sql server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27776/Dynamic-Pivoting-in-SQL-Server). Hope this helps!